# Exterior algebra as a complex of vector bundles and an element in relative K-theory

Tags: vector-bundles, topological-k-theory

There is a description of relative $K$-theory in terms of complexes of vector bundles. The following is an excerpt from Atiyah's book.

> Let $V$ be a complex vector space and consider the exterior algebra $\Lambda^{*}(V)$. We can regard this in a natural way as a complex of vector bundles over $V$. Thus we put $E_{i}=V\times\Lambda^{i}(V)$, and define $V\times\Lambda^{i}(V)\rightarrow V\times\Lambda^{i+1}(V)$ by $(v,w)\rightarrow(v,v\wedge w)$. If $\dim V=1$, the complex has just one map and this is an isomorphism for $v\neq 0$. Thus it defines an element of $K(B(V),S(V))\cong\tilde{K}(S^{2})$ where $B(V),S(V)$ denote the unit ball and unit sphere of $V$ with respect to some metric. Moreover this element is, from its definition, the canonical generator of $\tilde{K}(S^{2})$ except for a sign $-1$.

I don't quite understand the last two statements. Why is it an element of $K(B(V),S(V))$? And where does the sign $-1$ come from?

Comment: If you understand why 'the complex has just one map and this is an isomorphism for v≠0' it's hard to see what is your problem with 'it defines an element of $K(B(V),S(V))$'. What definition of relative $K$-theory are you using?

Comment: My understanding was that complexes of vector bundles on $X$ which are acyclic on a subspace $Y$ define elements of $K(X,Y)$. I am unsure about why we have $B(V)$ and $S(V)$ in the above situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you probably know the answer by now, here it is in case someone else stumbles upon this question.

About the first statement: you can define relative $K$-groups via triples $[E_0,E_1; \sigma]$ consisting of two bundles $E_i$ over $X$ and a homomorphism $\sigma \colon E_0 \to E_1$, which is an isomorphism over the subspace $Y$. In fact it doesn’t matter if $\sigma$ is only defined over $Y$. (That’s what Atiyah is trying to tell you in that products section). 
In the case at hand you simply put $\Lambda^0 \mathbb{C}$ and $\Lambda^1\mathbb{C}$ as trivial bundles over $B^2$ and identity them over $S^1$ by the map mentioned above.
Doing so yields the “reduced” Hopf bundle over $S^2$.

The sign now arises from the fact that the *dual* of that bundle is (at least in Atiyah’s definition) the Bott element, the generator of $\widetilde{K}(S^2)$. In the proof of Bott periodicity it is explained why taking the dual gives the inverse in $K$-theory.