# Defining Bott Class by relative $K$-theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, k-theory, topological-k-theory

I am really confused with this construction of Bott Class in [Page 127, Example 8.4.12](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/jeber_02/skripten/mainfile.pdf)

> If $V$ is a complex vector space of dimension $n$, we form the complex 
>   $$ 0 \rightarrow \wedge^0 V \rightarrow \wedge^1 V \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow \wedge ^nV \rightarrow 0 $$ 
>   of trivial vector bundles over $V$.

What does this mean? So we have $n$ trivial vector bundles, $V \times \Bbb C^{\binom{n}{k}}$?

> The map $\wedge^pV \rightarrow \wedge^{p+1}V$ is given by $w \mapsto v \wedge w$. Now we pass to complex conjugate bundles. IT is clear that if $f:V \rightarrow W$ is a $\Bbb C$ linear map then $f:\bar{V} \rightarrow \bar{W}$.

What does $\bar{V}$ mean? Where do we use "passing to the complex conjugate"?

> Denote the resulting class $b_V \in K^0(DV,DS)$.

(i) How is $b_V$ induced from all the things above? Is this by the *wrapping* defined on pg 126?

(ii) how is $b_V$ dependent on $f$ or $W$.

Comment: Although I do not see the purpose of the bundle $\wedge^i V$, it is obvious that it stands for the product bundle $V \times \wedge^i V$. The map $\wedge^i V \to \wedge^{i+1} V$ is defined *fiberwise* by $\omega \mapsto v \wedge \omega$ for all $v \in V$. Any complex vector space $V$ can be given the *complex conjugate structure* by defining a new scalar multiplication via $\lambda * v = \overline{\lambda} \cdot v$. This vector space is denoted by $\overline{V}$. The same construction applies to vector bundles (fiberwise). But it is not clear to me what the "resulting class" $b_V$ should be.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642167/exterior-algebra-as-a-complex-of-vector-bundles-and-an-element-in-relative-k-the?rq=1 $\bar{V}$ is the complex conjugate of a vector space, you can look it up on Wikipedia. Please note that there is a typo: $DS$ should be $SV$. The sequence is exact everywhere outside zero, so gives a class in $(V,V\smallsetminus \{0\})\cong(DV,SV)$. The passage to conjugate is related to the fact the the Bott generator is defined of index $-1$, so in this picture the section $z\mapsto \bar{z}$. This answers your (i). Question (ii): $f$ and $W$ were only examples